# Loop For com Zip(), como selecionar a quantidade de registros?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho esse código que funciona normalmente

```
    def pdd(number, entrada):
        for i, j, k, l, m in zip(entrada[:-1], entrada[1:], entrada[2:], entrada[3:], entrada[4:]):
            if number in i:
                print([j, k, l, m])

    list_pad = [[1, 9], [1, 15], [1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [1, 15], [1, 14], [1, 15], [1, 16], [1, 17], [1, 18]]

    pdd(15, list_pad)
```

Saida:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13]]
[[1, 14], [1, 15], [1, 16], [1, 17]]
```

Porém ao invés de imprimir 4 registros,  gostaria de poder definir a quantidade por parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
pdd(15, list_pad, 6)
```

E deveria sair:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [1, 15], [1, 14]]
```

Ou

```
pdd(15, list_pad, 2)
```

E sair:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 11]]
[[1, 14], [1, 15]]
[[1, 16], [1, 17]]
```

Comment: Poderia colocar exemplos de algumas chamadas desta função e qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu reformulei meu post, mais resumido e com exemplos, veja se entendeu agora.

Comment: O que exatamente a função precisa fazer?

Comment: Basicamente ela vai analisar a entrada, que no caso é uma lista com pequenas listas. Então analisa a entrada, e ao identificar um item (lista) que tenha o número passado pelo parâmetro `number` , ela vai imprimir os próximos 4 itens (listas).

Isso o código já faz, mas eu gostaria de poder definir a quantidade por um parâmetro passado para o função (ao invés de 4)

Comment: E se a lista que possuir o valor for a última?

Comment: Então não imprime, pois depois dela não haverá a quantidade que eu definir. O código já faz isso, ele não imprime se não atender a quantidade. O que eu queria mesmo era poder definir quantos itens (listas) imprimir, definindo por parâmetro.